# How to get method name in Android?

Tags: java, android, spring

I've been using this instruction to get the name of a method which is currently being used.

```
currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName()
```

It works fine when I developed Spring Framework or other simple programmings. 
However, It seems it works differently in Android Studio. I get time instead of the name of a method.

The reason why I try to use this instruction is for debugging. I used to use

```
Log.d(TAG, "Method()");
```

However, The problem when I use this... I should type its method name each. So, To implement this instruction in all the different methods with the same instruction. I found out using currentTrace(). But when I use this on Android Studio. I just get 'geStackTrace' instead of the current method name.

Is there any way to implement it correctly or better way for debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
StackTraceElement[] stacktraceObj = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
stacktraceObj[1].getMethodName();
```

For further reference, checkout the links

https://www.badprog.com/android-api-getting-the-current-method-name-with-stacktraceelement

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Throwable.html#getStackTrace()

Comment: This is the exact code the OP posted and said is not working. `currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName()`

Comment: I already used it. And that doesn't work on Android Studio. That's why I asked. I haven't found the right method yet.

Answer (score 2):

If typing it out every-time is the issue use the default live templates for log statements.

Use <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd>(<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>j</kbd> in windows) and look for **logd**, **logi**, **logw** or **loge**.

By default it prints the method and a colon. You can customize it in preferences.

There's **logt** for creating a TAG too.

Comment: I know that sort of thing already. However, my question was in the bigger picture. In my case, I put `Log.d(TAG, method+msg)`. But for `TAG`, once I declare it in the field, I can keep using it anywhere in the class or even in other classes. But for the method name, It is a kind of a trouble. I don't need to change the msg, I just need to copy and paste into each method this in Eclipse. It does all the work: `System.out.println(TAG, currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName()+"() = ");` This is very simple. I am trying to find a way to do that on Android Studio.